# Error in using vector pointer in a function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector

I have this code, but it won't compile and i can't understand what is wrong - i guess the pointering of the vector is not correct. 
My idea was to collect some numbers in main() and store them in a vector and array, and then pass the memory address of them to a function, and using a pointers to print the data stored.

I came up with this when i read something about pointers which said that i should use them in order to save memory, so IMO the code below will not copy the contents of the vector and the array but use a pointer to access their location in memory - that's what i want to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void function(vector<int>* a, int *s)
{
    cout << "function starts.." << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<a->size();i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << endl;
        cout << s[a[i]] << endl;
    }
    cout << "function ends..." << endl;
}


int main(void)
{
    vector<int> m;
    int s[102];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        m.push_back(i*i);
        s[i*i] = i-2;
    }
    function(&m, &s);
    return 0;
}
```

I receive several errors on compiling, something is wrong.

Please tell me what's wrong with my code and how to fix it. thank you...

Comment: Is it part of your question to guess on the compilation errors you get? ;-)

Comment: I have taught C and C++ programming for years, so I am very good at guessing already since the usual problem description is "doesn't work". The Crystal Ball I bought from eBay also helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should pass the vector by reference, not by pointer:

```
void function(vector<int>& a, int *s)
```

And then

```
function(m, ...);
```

Using [] on a pointer to a vector would certainly cause strange problems because it behaves as if a pointed to an array of std::vectors (while it actually only points to one). The vectors itself are never indexed by that. You could also use `(*a)[...]` to index the vector by the pointer.

Comment: make sure when you make the change above to make the call like this: `function(m, s);`

Comment: Downvoting because this is dangerous advice--many coding standards advise never passing by non-const reference, and there's good reason for that. At the very least, the vector reference should be const. But this answer also doesn't address the real problem, which is that a pointer needs to be dereferenced before it's used. Replacing a[i] with (*a)[i] would be sufficient and might be more helpful to readers who are trying to understand this issue.

Answer (score 2):

if you insist in parsing by pointer then the correct syntax shoulld be:

```
void function(vector<int>* a, int *s[]) 
{ 
    cout << "function starts.." << endl; 
    for(int i=0;i<a->size();i++) 
    { 
        cout << (*a)[i] << endl; 
        cout << (*s)[(*a)[i]] << endl; 
    } 
    cout << "function ends..." << endl; 
}
```

Comment: error: cannot convert 'int (*)[102]' to 'int**'
It's not working.

Comment: Sorry read AndreyT comment below. But please call funtion(m,s) and parse by reference instead.

Answer (score 1):

(corrected)

`&s` is in fact `int(*)[102]`: pointer to a pointer to an array of 102 items.

You should just say

```
function(&m, s);
```

This is because by old C legacy rule, an array is essentially a const pointer to its item with index 0. So `s` is already `int*`

Comment: `&s` is *not* `int **`. `&s` is `int (*)[102]`. Array is not a const pointer. In value context it might appear so, but not in this case, when address is taken.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Anyway, `&s` is not a `int*`, it would have sufficed to pass `s` as argument.

Answer (score 1):

First of all in the main program s is a pointer to an int, while m is a vector. Thus the function call should be as follows:

function(&m, s);

Secondly in the function a is a pointer to a vector, so should be indexed as follows: (*a)[i].

However you should really be using const references to pass your vector around:

void function(const vector& a, int *s)
{
..
cout << a[i] << endl;
..
}

And call it like:

function(m, s);

Answer (score 0):

This version works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void function(const vector<int>& a, int s [102])
{
    cout << "function starts.." << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<(int)a.size();i++)
    {
        cout << a [i] << endl;
        cout << s[a [i]] << endl;
    }
    cout << "function ends..." << endl;
}


int main(void)
{
    vector<int> m;
    int s[102];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        m.push_back(i*i);
        s[i*i] = i-2;
    }
    function(m, s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice, it works. But as i can see s is not passed as pointer - why ? I would also like to pass a pointer to s in the function so i don't pass the whole array to the function - is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Passing the whole array by value is not good practice. I'd use

"void function(const vector<int>& a, int *s)"

and call it as 

"function(m, s);"

Comment: @VaiolsBorn: It is passed as a pointer - you can't pass an array by value in C++. `int s[102]` in the parameters is completely equivalent to `int s[]` (the size is ignored anyway) and `int* s` (array decays to pointer anyway).

Comment: Here it is:

void function(const vector<int>& a, int *s)
{
    cout << "function starts.." << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<(int)a.size();i++)
    {
  cout << a [i] << endl;
        cout << s[a [i]] << endl;
    }
    cout << "function ends..." << endl;
}